# Magento CE 2.1.X Stable version

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

**I Want to Migrate to Magento so which *Magento 2.1.X* version is stable**

Answer (score 0):

The version 2.1.6 was issued last week and fix [some points of the previous version](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.6CE.html) (performance mainly). In my opinion, the latest is always the most stable if you speak about minor. Speaking of major, it can be that some bugs persist after new developments.

You'll be surprised by the performances of magento 2 if you did not touch it before...